# logging error within a call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, command-line-interface

How can I log a fatal error occuring within a call_user_func_array?
Its within a CLI script that runs as a daemon.
I would like to log when an error occurs, but instead it always throws the error message back.

things that I tried but couldn't make it work:

```
try {call_user_func_array()} catch (Exception $e ) {do_log}
```

or

```
ob_start ();
try {call_user_func_array()} catch (Exception $e ) {do_log}
```

or

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
```

or

```
ini_set('error_log',$baseDir.'/Jobque_error.log');
fclose(STDIN);
fclose(STDOUT);
fclose(STDERR);
$STDIN = fopen('/dev/null', 'r');
$STDOUT = fopen($baseDir.'/Jobque_application.log', 'ab');
$STDERR = fopen($baseDir.'/Jobque_daemon.log', 'ab');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot catch a fatal error. It is fatal so your script dies and there is nothing you can do about it.

Actually, a function registered via `register_shutdown_handler` will still execute but you cannot get a backtrace etc. so that's pretty useless.

The only possible logging of a fatal error is via the `log_errors` php.ini setting.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but yes you *can* catch a fatal error.  Use `error_get_last()` inside of the function that you pass to `register_shutdown_handler()`.  `error_get_last()` gives you an associative array of error details.  If its `type` property equals `E_ERROR`, it was a fatal error that was caught.  This works since PHP 5.2.